# Possible to test a boolean array elements in a range?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, do-while

Consider a boolean array with four elements. Initially, all elements are false. The do-while loop will execute some tests and change each element's state until until all four elements are true.

```
boolean[] pickedSuits = new boolean[4];

do {
    ...some testing...

} while (pickedSuits[0] != true && pickedSuits[1] != true && pickedSuits[2] != true && pickedSuits[3] != true);
```

Is there a Java way to compare a *range* of elements instead of testing each one individually? I'm thinking without a for-loop, something like:

```
while (pickedSuits[0-3] != true);
```

Comment: Yes, there is a Java way: Write your own helper method: `boolean isAllTrue(boolean[] arr, int start, int end)`. Usually in a method like that, the `end` index is *exclusive*, meaning that your call would be `isAllTrue(pickedSuits, 0, 4)`.

Comment: @rburny Doesn't do the *range* part, but otherwise same thing. Of course, OP *is* checking full array, so maybe it is truly a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is no boolean stream, you can use an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) for this.

```
do {
    ...
} while (IntStream.range(0, pickedSuits.length).noneMatch(i -> pickedSuits[i]));
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can write a helper method:

```
boolean rangeIsTrue(boolean[] arr, int start, int end) {
    for(int i = start; i < end; i++) if(!arr[i]) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Generally should be `i < end` for an exclusive end value, which is the Java norm.

Comment: Sorry, I did a search but that thread didn't turn-up. Should I delete that post?